# Modificar doubleBackToExitPressedOnce android stuido

Tags: java, android, app, studio

Alguien puede decirme como quitar este código y hacerlo para que vaya para atrás en las páginas que navego en vez de salir cuando pulso dos veces?

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Pulsa dos veces para salir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola si deseas que la navigación hacia atrás sea la clásica, entonces deberas borrar toda la función. de por si solo se sobreescribe el método `onBackPressed` cuando se quiere cambiar el comportamiento clásico cuando se hace back o agregar alguna validación. Podrías intentar borrar toda esa función si no requieres agregar alguna validación o podrías dejarlo como :

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    // agregar alguna validación si se requiere
    // luego llamar a super.onBackPressed()
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Por otro lado, si quiere manejar el back con alguna lógica particular, entonces en el método anterior ya no deberias llamar a `super.onBackPressed()`. Este método lo que hace es hacer el back ( retroceder de pantalla o si solo existe una pantalla minimizarla).

Espero te ayude :)